# Replace the whitespaces from ion-selected value?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I tried to replace the value from my **`ion-select` component** like this :

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="musicDirection" name="musicDirection" (ngModelChange)="test()">
  <ion-option *ngFor="let musicDirection of this.musicDirections">
      {{musicDirection}}
   </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**Function :**

```
 test(){
    this.musicDirection.replace(/\s/g, "");
    console.log(this.musicDirection);
 }
```

But it doesn't work.

Here a screenshot from my console.log

[image: Here a screenshot from my console.log]

> **How I can replace it ?**

Comment: You need to save the replaced value back to the variable.
`this.musicDirection = this.musicDirection.replace(/\s/g, "");`

Comment: oh! you´re right! thanks